# Where can c(digit) be found in n(number)

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop

```
n = int(input("Unesite n: "))
c = int(input("Unesite c: "))

def where(n, c):
    where = []
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        dig = i
        while dig > 0:
            if dig % 10 == c:
                where.append(i)
                break
            dig //= 10
    print(where)
```

The answer to this question is probably stupid but... :/
For input n=22 and c=1 output is **[1, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 21]**.
I am curious how to remove [] from the output, f string, or something?
I want the output to look something like "From number 1 to {n}, digit {c} is shown in numbers: {where(n, c)}.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. "c" and "n" are meaningless without context, so your title isn't very helpful in describing your question. What is this code supposed to do? You're printing a list, so yes, it will show with `[]` around it. What part of this tries to print anything like "From number 1 to {n}, digit {c} is shown in numbers: {where(n, c)}"?

Comment: Looks like homework to me...

Comment: Code needs to print numbers between 1 and n(including n) that have digit c in them.
Etc. n=22 and c=1 output is [1, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 21].
I am clear that I am printing a list.
My question is can I edit the appearance of the list, to be more specific can I remove [] from the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def where(n, c):
    where = []
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        dig = i
        while dig > 0:
            if dig % 10 == c:
                where.append(i)
                break
            dig //= 10
    for e in where:
        print(e, end= " ")
```

then the output will be

```
1 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 21
```

Answer (score 1):

here is another solution:

```
def where(n, c):
 where = []
 for i in range(1, n + 1):
     dig = i
     while dig > 0:
         if dig % 10 == c:
             where.append(i)
             break
         dig //= 10
 print(str(where)[1:-1])


n = 22
c = 1
where(n, c)
```